# PHP, Wordpress Query, Combine Matched Results in 1

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running a query in Wordpress to get a list of speakers from a custom post type. I only need one instance of each speaker returned even though a speaker may show up multiple times as meta for the custom post types.

So for example, if I query and get a list back like this:
Bob, Bob, Bob, John, Sally, Bob, Bob, John, Bob

I would want it to be:
Bob, John, Sally

I'm not sure how to group all the matched results with PHP.

Here is my query:

```
global $post;
  $args = array (
    'post_type' = 'event',
    'posts_per_page' = -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_query' => array (
      'relation' => 'AND'
      array (
        'key' => 'pt_eventSpeakerType',
        'value' => 'Lead Speaker',
        'compare' => '=',
      ),
    ),
  );
$posts = get_posts($args);
if($posts) :
  foreach($posts as $post):setup_postdata($post);
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pt_eventSpeaker' true).'<br>';
  endforeach;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post what the example results are? and what you want back? For example a simple array like `[ 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob']` only needs `array_unique` if it's nested `[['name'=>'Bob']]` its harder but you may be able to use `array_column($array, 'name')` and then do unique, depending what you want the results to be.  Because it's meta-data its probably serialized which means it's a poor choice for optimizing with just SQL (if its serialized). Therefore it's a simple transform of the array data.

Comment: The most efficient way would probably be to get the post ID after joining and grouping on the names with `$wpdb->get_results()` and then going from there.  This will only work if `pt_eventSpeaker` is not serialized data.  I don't thing you can do group by in `get_posts` etc.

Comment: Something like this `SELECT m2.post_id FROM wp_posts AS p JOIN wp_postmeta AS m1 ON p.ID = m1.post_id AND m1.meta_key = "pt_eventSpeakerType" AND m1.meta_value="Lead Speaker" JOIN wp_postmeta AS m2 ON p.ID = m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key = "pt_eventSpeaker" GROUP BY m2.meta_value`  Not sure if it will work, just doing it in my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This may not be the best way, but it works and doesn't require any alteration of the query: I found a PHP array function called `array_unique`

First I have to return all the speaker names in a `foreach` loop and then convert that to an array of its own. It gets rid of all the other objects returned by `WP_Query`.

Then use the `array_unique` function to sort those into an array of single entries for each speaker name.

Finally, using another `foreach` to loop through those names and output them.

```
global $post;
  $args = array (
    'post_type' = 'event',
    'posts_per_page' = -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_query' => array (
      'relation' => 'AND'
      array (
        'key' => 'pt_eventSpeakerType',
        'value' => 'Lead Speaker',
        'compare' => '=',
      ),
    ),
  );
$posts = get_posts($args);
if($posts) :
  foreach($posts as $post):setup_postdata($post);
    $speakerName = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pt_eventSpeaker', true);
    $speakers[]= $speakerName;
  endforeach;
  $names = array_unique($speakers);
  foreach($names as $name) :
    echo $name.'<br>';
  endforeach;
else :
  echo 'No Posts Found.';
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Just a note, meta queries are *not indexed* by the database by default, and thus can have a tremendous impact on larger sites, resulting in a significant slowdown when running the query. If you plan on having this website running at a large scale, you may want to considering a better relational format for `Lead Speaker`, such as a taxonomy/tax query which *is* indexed.

Answer (score 0):

from what you described, I assume that you are not creating SQL query correctly. Method `get_posts($args);` is probably not returning distinct results, that may be the problem with your duplicated values. I hope it helps.

Comment: get_posts() is the same as WP_Query() and both are the Wordpress way to query. I get distinct results for each row. For example, each speaker name would come along with a post ID. But I just want to know how to group rows so that I just have 1 of each.